# How can I play transparent videos in GVRKit?

Tags: swift, opengl-es, google-cardboard, google-vr, avkit

I am creating a Virtual Reality app using Google's GVRKit for Google Cardboard.

I need to implement transparency in GVRVideoRenderer.
The use case for this is for playing a video over a 360° photo background to give a VR effect.

I have used Chroma Key blending with an input and mask image to implement the transparency in AVPlayerItem:

```
let filter = AlphaFrameFilter()   
filter.inputImage = request.sourceImage.cropped(to: sourceRect)     
filter.maskImage = request.sourceImage.cropped(to: alphaRect).transformed(by: transform)
```

Unfortunately, when passing this into GVRVideoRenderer, the view still has a black background.

How can I fix this?